# Continuous Integration: running Jenkins Build on newly created EC2 Instance using AWS Cloudformation+OpsWorks, What is best practice?

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, continuous-integration, aws-opsworks, aws-cloudformation

I'm looking for the best practice.

The current situation is:
I have a running Staging Instance on which Jenkins is installed. In Jenkins I have created a Job/Project which uses AWS Cloudformation and Opsworks to create a new EC2 Instance. I used Opsworks, Chef and Berkshelf to automatically download our GIT Repository from Bitbucket to the newly created EC2 Instance.

My Goal:
I want to setup a CI environment. I want to manually start the Jenkins Job on my Staging server. Then a complete new EC2 Instance is set up using Cloudformation and OpsWorks. (Up to this point everything already works and this way should be a good practice!?) Now I want to automatically execute my tests on the newly created EC2 Instance and save the results (tests passed?, results of code quality measuring tools (CodeSniffer,....) in Jenkins on my Staging Server. After running the tests I want to terminate the EC2 Instance.

I think I could install a Jenkins Slave on the created EC2 Instance and use my Staging Server as Jenkins master.

Is this best practice?

How could I achieve running tests on a fresh test server, saving results and shuting down the server afterwards?

Thank's for your help!

Best regards,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the jenkins AWS plugin, it should take care of creating a slave and registering it with jenkins for you:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Amazon+EC2+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

You might find this helpful - https://github.com/jadekler/git-chef-basic-jenkins-ci. It's a little bit of chef around spinning up jenkins on an EC2 instance. You can adjust the jenkins jobs / chef scripts as needed (maybe you don't need ruby/java but instead need go or python). Welcome to help further if needed.